Can't drag text to serialized field even after using TextMeshProUGUI and adding using TMPro;
I am new to unity with C#. I am facing an issue that seems to go nowhere .
following an older tutorial but in the version I am using here seems to be no editor for me ? I have no idea why. this is the code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class ItemCollector : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int cherries = 0;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI cherriesText;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Cherry"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            cherries++;
            cherriesText.text = "Cherries: " + cherries;
        }
    }
}

and here is an image

I am pretty sure that I followed the steps correctly, what am I doing wrong here dear Pros?
I was expecting the text to be used there

which component you are using for text?

The component you are trying to drag and drop onto the field, must have a TextMeshProUGUI component attached to it. Do make sure that is the case. Serialized fields will only take a dragged and dropped item if it matches the type defined for the field, and that specific type is attached to the dragged components.
Also check whether the Component is "Text" or "TextMeshProUGUI".
Need a bit more information before we can help properly, tbh.

Thank you. The issue was that I was dragging the component to the script in the inspector onto the serialized field, This problem was solved when I dragged the text on the "Player" component that had the script (serialized field) instead of the script itself (serialized field).
